# Low Search Related Child in List

Tags: playa, low-search, relationships

I am working on a client site and they have a search form which we are using Low Search for. Two current search fields for `keywords` and `topics` (a Playa field) work fine.

I am working on the third field where we need to filter by the `position` (text input) field of a related employee (Playa field).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<select id="position" name="child:news_related_employees[]">
    <option value="">All</option>
    {exp:query sql="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id) AS entry_ids, field_id_34 AS p_position FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_34 != '' GROUP BY field_id_34 ORDER BY field_id_34 ASC"}
    <option value="{entry_ids}">{p_position}</option>
    {/exp:query}
</select>
```

The query works fine, I get a comma separated list of `entry_id`s per unique position, however the form does not return any results. I assume that's because it is trying to match the entire string of `entry_id`s to an employee in the Playa field.

Can anyone shed some light on this or know of a way to do what we need? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low Search expects a pipe `|` as a value separator. You can [define that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in the `GROUP_CONCAT` clause of your query. So try this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR '|') AS entry_ids
```